# строка состояния в QT designer

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, qt5

как добавить строку состояния в виджет(не в главное окно) в Qt5 Desiner?возможно после создания виджета и конвертации в py,  в py уже дописать, или в дизайнере есть какой нить лейбл или бокс или ещё что то там в который можно передать запущена программа или остановлена,может лампочку ))

Comment: Добавляйте QStatusBar и прижмите его пружиной вниз. Кст, а почему нельзя использовать QMainWindow? Он ведь удобный и у него уже есть statusbar

Comment: да плин создал налепил всего в виджете и тут бац а статус (впринцие не нужен) но всё таки!а откуд его добавлять в приложении дизайнера не нашёл чтот?или имеется ввиду в ру файле добавить? и что за пружина?

Comment: ну, на форме в дизайнере, там две пружины: вертикальные и горизонтальные. В коде у меня этим `addStretch` занимается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/9e86c381abbd78ff96a9ab35eb29a7d92bfd9ed0/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/append_custom_QStatusBar__with_icon) кастомного [QStatusBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QStatusBar.html). [Тут иконка](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/9e86c381abbd78ff96a9ab35eb29a7d92bfd9ed0/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/append_custom_QStatusBar__with_icon/light-bulb-icon_34400.png).

Код:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class Widget(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.indicator = Qt.QLabel()
        self.indicator.hide()
        self.indicator.setFixedSize(32, 32)
        self.indicator.setScaledContents(True)
        self.indicator.setPixmap(Qt.QPixmap('light-bulb-icon_34400.png'))

        self.line_edit = Qt.QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit.textEdited.connect(self._on_text_edited)

        self.status_bar = Qt.QStatusBar()
        self.status_bar.addPermanentWidget(self.indicator)
        self.status_bar.setSizeGripEnabled(False)  # Убираем снизу-справа уголок

        main_layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 0)  # Сверху, слева и справа отступ 5, внизу его нет
        main_layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        main_layout.addStretch()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.status_bar)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def _on_text_edited(self, text):
        # Показываем сообщение на 2 секунды
        self.status_bar.showMessage(text, msecs=2000)

        # Показываем лампочку
        self.indicator.show()

        # Через 2 секунды лампочка исчезнетв
        Qt.QTimer.singleShot(2000, self.indicator.hide)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

PS. Возможно можно было проще, но получилось как получилось. Тот же алгоритм будет если сделать на форме.